# Mysql update query set username ='tester' and phone ='12345' where id =1

Tags: sql-update

Sometime, I make a mistake that use **and** instead of **comma**, what will be the result of it?

```
update table set username ='tester' and phone ='12345' where id =1
```

Comment: where is the table name

Comment: is table is your table name because it is a keyword in sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case your query is

```
update `table` set username ='tester' and phone ='12345' where id =1
```

then it will perform an 'AND' operation on your data in **username** and **phone** columns and will return a result as **0** or **1** and it will set that result into your table username column

you can try this by running these queries in your mySQL

```
SELECT 'test' AND '1223'

SELECT '1234' AND '1223'
```

where output of first query is 0 because they are different and the output of second query is 1 [read this to understand AND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and)

Comment: so username will become 0 or 1 and the value of phone will not be changed?

Comment: yes you can try it on any table run a similar type of query no matter if their column name and table name is change

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set username ='tester' and phone ='12345' where id =1
```

this is not the correct syntax to write an update query this will generate an error because TABLE is a key word in SQL do you mean

```
update `table` set username ='tester' and phone ='12345' where id =1
```

UPDATE syntax is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,... 
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

as you can see that

**UPDATE** then **table_name**

**SET** then **ColumnName = value ,  ColumnName = value.....**

**WHERE** then **Any Condition**